# How to set correct indentation of html jinja blocks in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jinja2, indentation

This is what the code currently looks like:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
{% if messages %}
{% for msg in messages %}
<p>{{ msg }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}

<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endblock content %}
```

And this is how I want it to look:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for msg in messages %}
            <p>{{ msg }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}

<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endblock content %}
```

I tried changing VSC settings and installing various extensions, but autoformatting code that works perfectly in python code removes indentation in jinja blocks.

Answer (score 1):

The `djlint-vscode` extension fixed this for me. You may need to explicitly switch the syntax mode to "Jinja2" instead of "Jinja2 HTML." That should do it. You can manually invoke the indent command with the (default) keyboard shortcut `CTRL+SHIFT+I`. Also you need to install `djlint` for whatever Python interpreter you're  using.

Comment: I installed the `djlint-vscode` extension and it doesn't work. I get an error ```Failed to get Python interpreter from Python extension.``` And I have no option to select Jinja2 only Jinja in several versions :(

Comment: @Keldro, you may need to install `djlint` manually for whatever interpreter you want to use. `/path/to/your/interpreter/python3 -m pip install djlint`